# How do you Run ADB commands with Qt Creator?

Tags: android, c++, bash, qt, adb

Currently I am attempting to get a push button in Qt to run the following command: `adb reboot`.  I am on a MAC and when I run this command in my console it reboots the `Android` device connected to my computer via `USB`. I have read the forums online and have been unable to solve this problem. Here are some of my attempts when trying to call `adb reboot` in Qt:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess::startDetached("/bin/bash", QStringList()<< "-c" << "export PATH=${PATH}:/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/");
    QProcess::startDetached("/bin/bash", QStringList()<< "-c" << "adb reboot");
    QProcess::startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "-c" << "adb reboot");
    QProcess::startDetached("/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/", QStringList()<< "-c" << "adb reboot");
}
```

This is the output of my console when I click the button:

```
Starting /Users/ddelorenzo/Documents/QaGUI/QaGUI/QaGUI.app/Contents/MacOS/QaGUI..
/bin/bash: adb: command not found
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the Android SDK installed correctly? It just looks like `adb` isn't added to `path`.

Comment: `QProcess::startDetached("/Users/ddelorenzo/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform‌​-tools/adb", QStringList()<< "reboot");`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use [this method](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qprocess.html#startDetached-2):

> bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString & command) [static]
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Starts the command command in a new process, and detaches from it. Returns true on success; otherwise returns false.
>
> Argument handling is identical to the respective start() overload.
>
> After the command string has been split and unquoted, this function behaves like the overload which takes the arguments as a string list.

Therefore, I would write something like this:

```
if (!QProcess::startDetached("/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform‌​-tools/adb reboot"))
    qDebug() << "Failed to execute";
```

Comment: So when attempting to use this technique, I receive the "Failed to execute" output to my console. Im wondering if this is because the path is one on my local machine and in, potentially, no way linked to my QT project. When I run "echo Hello" as a command this works just fine. Do I have to include the ADB commands somewhere in my QT project? or call the command in a different way? Thanks for the previous help!

Comment: @ddelorezno: check if the command works when you run it manually.

Comment: When I run "adb reboot" in my console, it works just fine. However the /Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform‌​-tools/adb reboot this doesnt work. I have also tried, if (!QProcess::startDetached("adb reboot"))
    qDebug() << "Failed to execute";

Comment: When I run ./Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb reboot from the command line, this works. I also Tried to add the "./" to the startDetached, but this isnt working for me either.